# R - Horizontal Count of Variables with Values NOT EQUAL to -8

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, dplyr, count

I wish to create a new variable named "NumberChild" to specify the number of children EACH person has in the R data frame.

My data looks like this:

| Person ID | Child 1 ID | Child 2 ID | Child 3 ID | Child 4 ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10011 | 133088 | -8 | -8 | -8 |
| 10012 | 133088 | -8 | -8 | -8 |
| 10013 | 133077 | 133066 | -8 | -8 |
| 10014 | 122099 | 122089 | 122079 | -8 |
| 10015 | -8 | -8 | -8 | -8 |
| 10016 | -8 | -8 | -8 | -8 |

I wish my new variable "NumberChild" to look like this:
("-8" means this person has no such child)

| Person ID | Child 1 ID | Child 2 ID | Child 3 ID | Child 4 ID | NumberChild |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10011 | 133088 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 1 |
| 10012 | 133088 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 1 |
| 10013 | 133077 | 133066 | -8 | -8 | 2 |
| 10014 | 122099 | 122089 | 122079 | -8 | 3 |
| 10015 | -8 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 0 |
| 10016 | -8 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 0 |

What I tried with the dplyr package:

```
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(NumberChild = if_else(Child_1_ID != -8,1,0))
```

I only get the following: (Here, the new variable "NumberChild" only specify whether each person has at least 1 child or 0 child, it's a dummy variable - but I don't want a dummy variable, I want a numerical variable specifying the number of child)

| Person ID | Child 1 ID | Child 2 ID | Child 3 ID | Child 4 ID | NumberChild |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10011 | 133088 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 1 |
| 10012 | 133088 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 1 |
| 10013 | 133077 | 133066 | -8 | -8 | 1 |
| 10014 | 122099 | 122089 | 122079 | -8 | 1 |
| 10015 | -8 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 0 |
| 10016 | -8 | -8 | -8 | -8 | 0 |

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowwise()` with `c_across` here.

```
df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(NumberChild=sum(c_across(starts_with("Child"))!=-8))
```

The `rowwise` tells dplyr to look at one row at a time, rather than an entire column at a time which is the default. Then when you use `c_across` it will return a vector of values for the columns you select for each given row. Here we could the number of values not equal to -8 using the `sum(val != -8)` idiom.